# Prevent images from overlapping a fixed header

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed header with three tabs. On the rest of the page I have both text and images. I was able to have text scroll "under" the fixed header but the images overlap. I tried setting the background of the header as an image but that did not work. I also tried various z-index values but also lacked results. I'm posting the CSS with no z-index on the header because it doesn't affect the fixed header in terms of the overlap problem, but only shifts it off-center. Is there a way to fix this with CSS?

Thanks

HTML Code:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">

        <ul class="pull-right nav nav-pills">
            <li><a href="#">tab1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">tab2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">tab3</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div> 

<div class="content">
    <div class="container">

    <p>text here</p>
    <img src="image.jpg"/>
    <p>more text</p>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
body {
width: 100%
margin: auto;
background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

.header {
background: #FFFFFF;
position: fixed;
top: 0;
width: 100%
}

.toolbar a {
font-family: 'Raleway', sans-serif;
color: #5a5a5a;
font-size: 13px;
font-weight: bold;
text-transform: uppercase;
}

.toolbar li{
display: inline;
}

.content {
margin-top:100px;
z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: `z-index` only applies to positioned elements, so it has no effect on your `.content` at the moment. You should rather set a `z-index` on your `.header`.

Comment: I had previously tried that, but the `header` shifts completely to the left and the images still overlap. The z-index doesn't seem to affect images on the page.

Comment: Solved with the help of Bootstrap. I added navbar-fixed-top to `header` class. Thanks anyway CBroe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">

        <!--Tabs Here-->

    </div>
</div>
```

You have to use a Bootstrap feature (`navbar`) as opposed making the div a fixed element at the top of the page.